# HAProxy doesn't connect to MariaDB Galera cluster backend

Tags: mysql, mariadb, load-balancing, haproxy, galera

I'm new to MariaDB galera cluster load balancing and I'm trying to use HAProxy to do the load balancing. I have set up the MariaDB Galera cluster and it works perfectly.

In Haproxy, I have created a VIP for the DB cluster and if I look at the HAProxy statistics page it shows the VIP and all three nodes are green. This is how I have it configured:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# frontend_db_domain.com
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend db_domain.com

  bind ip:3306
  mode tcp
  option mysql-check user haproxy_check
  default_backend back_db_domain.com

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# backend_db_domain.com
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend back_db_domain.com
  balance roundrobin
    server db01.domain.com ip:3306 check
    server db02.domain.com ip:3306 check
    server db03.domain.com ip:3306 check
```

I configured a wordpress site to use the VIP address which is db.domain.com and wordpress shows `Error establishing a database connection`. If I use the db hostname or ip that hits the nodes directly everything works fine.

This is what shows in the HAProxy logs:

```
Mar 24 04:07:27 localhost haproxy[22096]: 1.2.3.4:56022 [24/Mar/2022:04:07:16.987] domain.com~ back_domain.com/nginx01.domain.com 68/0/1/10095/10164 500 2842 - - ---- 3/1/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /webdesigns/website1/ HTTP/1.1"
```

This is the nginx logs:

```
45.77.206.174 - - [24/Mar/2022:04:07:27 +0000] "GET /webdesigns/website1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 2539 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0" "1.2.3.4"
```

There is no firewall in place that would block anything between all these hosts. They can all connect to each other. This is how the db nodes are configured:

```
[mysqld]
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
#bind-address=0.0.0.0

# Galera Provider Configuration
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera-4/libgalera_smm.so

# Galera Cluster Configuration
wsrep_cluster_name="test_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://10.1.96.12,10.1.96.13,10.1.96.14"

# Galera Synchronization Configuration
wsrep_sst_method=rsync

# Galera Node Configuration
wsrep_node_address="10.1.96.14"
wsrep_node_name="db03"
```

Not sure what I am missing but I think I have a misconfiguration on the HAProxy side but not sure what it can be. I have other VIPs but they're for web servers and stuff like that which all work fine. This the first VIP I have issues with. I would appreciate any and all help.

Thank you!

Comment: AFAIK the user `haproxy_check` needs to have no password, was this created in the database? Can you manually verify the connection to each of the backends using a `mariadb` client? Can you `show global status like 'wsrep_%'` to ensure its ready in a cluster sense.

Comment: Hello

I have recreated the user without a password and it did not change the results. I can also confirm that the user was indeed created and given the proper permissions. When I try to connect to the database nodes from the haproxy host via the mysql client using the db vip I get the following error: 

ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

I ran the show global status command and everything is fine with the cluster itself. All three nodes can see each other and replication is on and working fine.

Comment: Is the haproxy failing to pass the traffic because of the check? I did look at the code of the mysql check and it was very old and made quite a few assumptions. Does a tcp check result in a working cluster?

Comment: Hello. I have removed the checks but it still did not connect. I can connect but if I connect directly to one of the nodes which kills the point of having a VIP with a back end to load balance the MySQL hosts. Does it have to do with the mode also? I know most VIPs use the http mode but does it have to be tcp or anything else for MySQL?

Comment: I would assume a tcp mode for MariaDB. I'm approaching the limit of my haproxy knowledge now.

Comment: So, this is what I had to do to fix this. I had a pair of haproxy host in http mode so I had to build a different pair of haproxy host in TCP mode for it to work since you can't mix the modes in haproxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is what I had to do to fix this.

From reading around, it seems for the MariaDB cluster to work in HAProxy you would have to do so in TCP mode. The original haproxy pair I had is in HTTP mode so the MariaDB cluster wasn't going to work.

I had to build a new haproxy pair and configure it in TCP mode and the cluster worked in HAProxy as intended. Unfortunately, it seems you can't mix modes in haproxy.

If anyone finds a way to mix modes or if it comes up in a future version that would be awesome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For me it helped to set the "mode tcp" in the frontend as well as in the backend:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# frontend_db_domain.com
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
frontend db_domain.com

  bind ip:3306
  mode tcp
  option mysql-check user haproxy_check
  default_backend back_db_domain.com

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# backend_db_domain.com
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
backend back_db_domain.com
  balance roundrobin
  mode tcp
  server db01.domain.com ip:3306 check
  server db02.domain.com ip:3306 check
  server db03.domain.com ip:3306 check
```

Answer (score 0):

cli ip a check your vip is work on haproxy hosts\

Comment: Hello

When I tried to connect to the mysql haproxy VIP using the mysql client I get the following error:

ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0

The command I ran was this

 mysql -h db.domain.com -u haproxy_root -e "show variables like 'server_id'"

Comment: vi my.cnf    bind-address=0.0.0.0

Comment: Hello. All three nodes have the bind-address configured as you have in your previous comment but it still doesn't connect. The wordpress site gets the Error Establishing a Database Connection. If I connect directly to one of the nodes it works. Something is not letting HAProxy pass the request to the back end and return a reply.